# Обработка одновременного нажатия нескольких кнопок в javafx

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть панель, на которой рисуются графики функций. С помощью этого метода на неё повешен слушатель. Предполагается, что, при нажатии на стрелки клавиатуры, график будет перемещаться, но когда я нажимаю одновременно две кнопки, график перемещается только в одну сторону, более того, когда я отпускаю одну из кнопок, вторая больше не регистрируется.
Я проверил это через `System.out.println()`, дело не в коде моего "полотна", а в том, как обрабатываются сразу несколько кнопок клавиатуры.

```java
setOnKeyPressed(keyEvent -> {
    switch (keyEvent.getCode()) {
        case UP: System.out.println("UP"); break;
        case DOWN: System.out.println("DOWN"); break;
        case RIGHT: System.out.println("RIGHT"); break;
        case LEFT: System.out.println("LEFT"); break;
    }
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы для эксперимента уберете выполнение кода, приводящее к изменениям на экране, то будут ли фиксироваться оба нажатия?

Comment: Я проверил с System.out.println(), вот скриншот.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь надо использовать `AnimationTimer`.

```java
boolean[] keysPressed = new boolean[4];

setOnKeyPressed(keyEvent -> {
    switch (keyEvent.getCode()) {
        case UP: keysPressed[0] = true; break;
        case DOWN: keysPressed[1] = true; break;
        case LEFT: keysPressed[2] = true; break;
        case RIGHT: keysPressed[3] = true; break;
    }
});

setOnKeyReleased(keyEvent -> {
    switch (keyEvent.getCode()) {
        case UP: keysPressed[0] = false; break;
        case DOWN: keysPressed[1] = false; break;
        case LEFT: keysPressed[2] = false; break;
        case RIGHT: keysPressed[3] = false; break;
    }
});

new AnimationTimer() {
    @Override
    public void handle(long now) {
        if (keysPressed[0]) System.out.println("UP");
        if (keysPressed[1]) System.out.println("DOWS");
        if (keysPressed[2]) System.out.println("LEFT");
        if (keysPressed[3]) System.out.println("RIGHT");
    }
}.start();
```